# File to rename by autoit

Tags: autoit

I was looking for help here, am copying file from one location and pasting in another folder, however i want rename with different name
Can you suggest how to complete this code?

```
Func Example()      
    If DirGetSize($sFldr1) <> -1 Then               
        Return False
    EndIf
    DirCreate($sFldr1)       
EndFunc   ;==>Example
Filecopy($var,$sFldr1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is called [FileMove](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileMove.htm).
Renaming is equivalent to moving the file to the same folder but with a different name.

See [the linked documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileMove.htm).

> Because AutoIt lacks a "FileRename" function, use FileMove() to rename
>   a file!

Add the `FileMove` command at the end of your script.